# Git: delete the contents of a folder for good across multiple branches

Tags: git

I am transferring an SVN repository into Git and need to remove all files within a specific directory (sites/default/files/*) from all branches and tags. The reason is that all files in this directory were accidentally committed long in the past and are now making the Git repository 900+ MB in size. This repository has not been shared yet so there are no worries about changing SHAs etc.

Any help? I've tried following the instructions at http://github.com/guides/completely-remove-a-file-from-all-revisions but they don't seem to work for me.

Comment: I found the command to run. It is as follows:

<pre>
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git ls-files sites/default/files | xargs git update-index --remove' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
</pre>

After that, cloning to a new local repo is the easiest way to purge all unneeded files from the database. Doing this cut down the size of the repository by 700MB!

In the end the problem here was that the files were being referenced by other branches and tags. "--tag-name-filter cat -- --all" ensured that the filter-branch command ran on everything.

Comment: You should probably write that as an answer, preferably clearly explaining what all the options did for you. It's also generally a good idea to upvote other answers you found significantly helpful (up to you to decide what "significantly" means).

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "don't seem to work"? It's hard to help without any specifics.

The thing that jumps out to me as most likely is that those instructions use `HEAD` for the ref to filter, so it'll only filter commits reachable from whatever you have checked out right now. You probably want to do this to all branches; instead of `git filter-branch ... HEAD` you could use `git filter-branch ... -- --all`. The `--` indicates end of filter-branch options, and the `--all` means to filter all refs.

The best general advice I can give is to read the [filter-branch man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch). It contains some examples as well.

Finally, remember that the old objects stay around in the repo. Debilski touched on this, mentioning that you have to prune the old objects (`git gc --prune=now`) or reclone the repo to see the size difference. This will work fine for you locally.

To get it cleaned on the remote... well, I believe that github will eventually run `git gc`, but it'll be using the default prune settings, so they won't be pruned for a couple weeks. Otherwise, you could delete and recreate your project. I'm not aware of any way to force a gc on github.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I received similar guidance on IRC that helped. Hopefully others with this same problem will find this answer on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tags in your repo, you’ll have to add `--tag-name-filter cat` to the `git filter-branch` command.

And of course, to see any effect of the filtering you’ll have to prune the commits – or better yet: clone the repo to somewhere else and see if it is smaller now.